# Having git and svn working together on same folder

Tags: git, svn

right now I need to have both git and svn synchronizing together in tthe same folder, so every change that's done on SVN gets ported to git and vice-versa.

I started by checking out the repository on SVN.
Then I did "git init", and "git remote add origin url..."
Since this is an already existing repository on both git and svn I had to do something like "git pull origin --allow-unrelated-histories" so git would be able to recognize that those files already existed.

The thing is that I still get a lot of changes to files on the SVN side, to files that are equal.

What's the correct way of doing this process, having both SVN and git tracking the same files?

Comment: Use Subgit or git-svn or some equivalent that is capable of managing synchronization of SVN and Git repos. Git and SVN have wildly different branching models, meaning that trying to just work with both natively out of the same on-disk location is going to end poorly.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only way I can go right now. This is going to be used for a smooth transition from svn to git and this folder will be used to keep for systems in sync.

Comment: It's *not* the only way you can go, and as I said, it's *not* going to work because of the different ways that SVN and Git handle branching. Git-svn, subgit, and equivalent tooling **will** allow you to make a smooth transition between SVN and Git, because those tools are actually capable of managing the differences between the branching models.